# the value in input is duplicating in my react app when user searches fastly in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, throttling

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      input: value,
    });
   throttledFetch(value)// api throttling for 500 ms
  };


  throttledFetch = value => {
    if (checkForNumber(value)) {
      this.callApi1(value);
    } else {
      this.callApi2(value);
    }
  };

  callApi1 = input => {
    const queryParams = input
      ? {
          url: URL1,
          resultCount: 75,
        }
      : {
          url: URL1,
          sort: 1,
        };
    this.apiRequest && this.apiRequest.cancel();
    this.apiRequest = makeCancelable(autocomplete(queryParams, input));
    this.apiRequest.promise
      .then(json => this.afterFetch({ list: json }))
      .catch(error => {
       
      });
  };
  callApi2= input => {
    this.apiRequest && this.apiRequest.cancel();
    this.apiRequest = makeCancelable(
      autocomplete(
        {
          url: URL2,
          resultCount: 75,
        },
        input
      )
    );
    this.apiRequest.promise
      .then(json =>
        this.afterFetch({ list: json })
      )
      .catch(error => {
      
      });
  };
<input onChange={handleChange}/>
```

The issue is when user searches fastly in mobile in a one go input is getting duplicated
for suppose, if user searches stack the value in input would be sststastacstack and it's not happening in desktop site,ios mobile and only happening in android mobile in chrome browser. What might be the issue?